# django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 30: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, templates

Error: django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 30: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

[This is the display i do get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5UEo.png)

Comment: Could we see the code? I don't see the "IF" tag block so if you forgot to add it then it will break. It could just be above the error code so It's hard to know for sure.

if you have a {% else %} and a  {% endif %} surely there must be a {% if  something %} tag as well.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, in order for other users to be able to help you please provide more context such as the input and expected output, tech stack etc. Adding the problematic code to the question itself would also help a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the response... kindly find the code below...

{% if access_records %)
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Site Name</th>
                <th>Date Accessed</th>
            </thead>

            {% for acc in access_records %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ acc.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ acc.date }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        {% else %}
        <p>NO ACCESS RECORDS FOUND</p>
        {% endif %}

Answer (score 1):

You ought to replace

`{% if access_records %)`

with

`{% if access_records %}`